# Resolving database locks in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, locks, database

I have 2 collections that I am doing a map reduce into a temporary collection, let's call them collection A and collection B and collection _queue. 
While I am doing the map reduce, users are trying to read and write to collection A. I am getting all sorts of locks and queued writes and reads.
I don't care if there are dirty reads or writes, is the a way to read and write to collection B and make it non-atomic? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Updating to mongo 3.2 addresses these locks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in MongoDB to specify anything on a query regarding it's lock policy.

First, you need to check if the time to acquire the lock is really an issue (you can use MongoDB internal Profiler for this : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/analyzing-mongodb-performance/#database-profiling)

Then, if you are not on the latest version of MongoDB (or if you upgrade to the latest without changing the storage engine), you can switch to WiredTigger that move from a lock by collection (for 3.x series, pre-3.x MongoDB have a lock by database) to a lock by document. So if you're using WiredTiger and still experience significant delays due to lock contention, I don't think you can do anything about it.

See the WiredTiger documentation here : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking at upgrading Mongo to 3.0+.

Comment: Upgrading to Mongo 3.2 and using the WiredTiger engine will solved the lock issue.